# Почему не могу передать из метода массив?

Tags: java, методы

Из-за объекста , как я думаю...Но как исправить не знаю.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Runners
{

  String name;
  double time;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println("Сколько всего бегунов?");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int number = scan.nextInt();



    if (number < 3)
    {
      System.out.print("Не может быть меньше 3 бегунов! ");
    }
    else
    {
        Runners[] run=new Runners[number];

        int x=0;
      while( x < run.length) {
        run[x]=new Runners();
       System.out.print("Фамилия бегуна?: ");

       run[x].name=scan.next();
       System.out.println("Время бегуна? ");

       run[x].time=scan.nextDouble();
      }
    }
   Sorting(Runners[]run ,int number);       // ошибка тут !!!!!!!!!!!!!
  }
  public void Sorting (Runners[]run ,int number){

        double resultsTMP;
        String sernameTMP;
        double minValue;
        int minValueInd;


         for (int i = 0; i<number; i++){
             minValue = run[i].time;
             minValueInd = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j<number; j++) {
                  if (run[j].time < minValue) {
                      minValue = run[i].time;
                      minValueInd = j;
                    } 
                   }
            if (minValueInd != i) {
            resultsTMP = run[i].time;
            run[i].time = run[minValueInd].time;
            run[minValueInd].time = resultsTMP;

            sernameTMP = run[i].name;
           run[i].name = run[minValueInd].name;
            run[minValueInd].name = sernameTMP;
                 }
         }
         for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
         System.out.println((i+1)+" "+ run[i].name + " "+ run[i].time);}
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorting(run ,number);

Comment: снова ошибка 1 error found:
File: F:\Di!\src\Runners.java  [line: 35]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable run
  location: class Runners

Comment: @Ди_, у вас run создается внутри области видимости else, и только там существует. Вытащите в область видимости метода или всегда класса (как его поле)

Answer (score 4):

1. Метод Sorting должен быть объявлен как static:

   public static void Sorting (Runners[] run ,int number)
2. При передачи аргументов в метод уже не надо указывать повторно тип данных этих аргументов:

   Sorting(run , number); // пишется так

   Sorting(Runners[]run ,int number);// это ошибка
3. Обьявлять инициализацию массива следует до цикла, а не в самом цикле while, так как после выхода из цикла массив больше не существует(читай про область видимости):

   String name;
   double time;
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

   ```
   System.out.println("Сколько всего бегунов?");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   int number = scan.nextInt();
   Runners[] run=new Runners[number]; // создавай тут

   if (number < 3)
   {
       System.out.print("Не может быть меньше 3 бегунов! ");
   }
   else
   {


       int x=0;
       while( x < run.length) {
           run[x]=new Runners();
           System.out.print("Фамилия бегуна?: ");

           run[x].name=scan.next();
           System.out.println("Время бегуна? ");

           run[x].time=scan.nextDouble();
       }
   }
   Sorting(run , number); // ошибка тут
   ```

   }
4. В это строчке:

   while( x < run.length)

x будет всегда меньше и следовательно цикл будет бесконечным!
в самом цикле напиши увеличение x на единицу!

**В итоге получается рабочая программа:**

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
class Runners
{

    String name;
    double time;
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Сколько всего бегунов?");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        Runners[] run=new Runners[number];

        if (number < 3)
        {
            System.out.print("Не может быть меньше 3 бегунов! ");
        }
        else
        {


            int x=0;
            while( x < run.length) {
                run[x]=new Runners();
                System.out.print("Фамилия бегуна?: ");

                run[x].name=scan.next();
                System.out.println("Время бегуна? ");

                run[x].time=scan.nextDouble();

                x++;
            }
        }
        Sorting(run , number); // ошибка тут
    }

    public static void Sorting (Runners[] run ,int number){

        double resultsTMP;
        String sernameTMP;
        double minValue;
        int minValueInd;


        for (int i = 0; i<number; i++){
            minValue = run[i].time;
            minValueInd = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j<number; j++) {
                if (run[j].time < minValue) {
                    minValue = run[i].time;
                    minValueInd = j;
                }
            }
            if (minValueInd != i) {
                resultsTMP = run[i].time;
                run[i].time = run[minValueInd].time;
                run[minValueInd].time = resultsTMP;

                sernameTMP = run[i].name;
                run[i].name = run[minValueInd].name;
                run[minValueInd].name = sernameTMP;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            System.out.println((i+1)+" "+ run[i].name + " "+ run[i].time);}
    }
}
```